# hadoop namenode is not formatting

Tags: hadoop

Here I am facing very strange issue in Ubuntu 12.04 Server, 64 Bit version. I installed java 7 JDK manually (Copy-pasted the jdk folder in /usr/lib/jvm and done lots of configuration to manage the java, javac and jps commands working properly). 
When formatting the name node by-

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

my shell shows:

```
$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated
```

and then suddenly returns to shell without formatting the namenode.
Also after starting the hadoop daemons by:

```
start-all.sh
```

they start by showing below message:

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-namenode-jci1.out
jci1: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-datanode-jci1.out
jci1: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-secondarynamenode-jci1.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-jobtracker-jci1.out
jci1: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-tasktracker-jci1.out
```

but when I try to see the processes by "jps" the output is like:

```
9351 -- main class information unavailable
9184 -- main class information unavailable
9520 -- main class information unavailable
9612 -- process information unavailable
9831 Jps
```

and after some time the jps shows only jps process:

```
9831 Jps
```

I am unable to figure-out why daemons are stopping just after start. Is it java issue?
Please give me advice what should I do to sort it out.

Comment: Is there any error information in the log files ? eg `/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-namenode-jci1.out` and `/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu1-jobtracker-jci1.out`

Comment: The tasktracker.log says:
    2014-02-19 04:43:27,422 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.

Comment: I don't have much idea about it except that it might be a corrupted JDK installation. Check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/378497/eclipse-error-on-ubuntu-13-10 It specifies some checks you can do.

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936745/hadoop-home-is-deprecated-hadoop

Comment: I have visited the link of askubuntu and followed the steps to verify the securities and uninstalled the openjdk-6 also, but with no advantage as the daemons are stopping with the same message.

Comment: @acbod ..I have visited the link, thanks for that I will do the needful to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this issue, because java is core of hadoop so JDK should be compatible and has all necessary files which are required by hadoop run time. In my case the culprit was another openjdk-6 which was parallel with Oracle_JDK 1.7, so I purged the previous installation and installed the oracle-java as only java alternative.
Now my namenode is formatting without any issue, also reviewing the log files of hadoop daemons solved my another problem.